# "Have never had" vs "never had"

Tags: tenses

My friends and I are discussing about a grammar question that hasn't reached a conclusion. We were at a birthday party last night and we ate pizza there. Immediately after eating the pizza, one of my friends said "It was nice! I **have never had** pizza before." I told him that it should be "It was nice! I ** never had** pizza before. I think the past tense should have been used because by the time he spoke about not having pizza, he actually had it. But I could not counter why he was wrong. Could someone please tell me "have never had" or "never had" which one he should have used?

Comment: The present perfect "have never had" is appropriate. At the time of the utterance, your friend's eating/enjoyment of the pizza had current relevance - no doubt they were still savouring their first encounter with pizza, so to speak. By contrast, the past perfect "had never had" would locate the eating entirely in the past; they may have had pizza since. But that sentiment would hardly be appropriate here, so the present perfect is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say both of them are correct, but the present-perfect one sounds more natural.

The present-perfect version basically says "We just had a good pizza – up until now, I've never had anything like this", while the past-perfect version says "We had a good pizza this evening – up until that pizza, I'd never had anything like it".

It's about point of view. *Your friend* views the moment of eating that pizza as very recent, hence he chose to use present perfect. *You* view that moment as occurring in the past, hence you chose to use past perfect. Both are OK, but I personally would use the present perfect tense.

Do note that in the future, where the moment of eating that pizza clearly belongs to the past, we *must* use the past perfect.

Also, in spoken English, have/had as helper verbs are (almost always) contracted to `'ve` and `'d`

Comment: I'm sure that this must be a duplicate, but I doubt that if I could find a previous incarnation it would have as clear and concise an answer as this. I've tidied your answer a bit.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Hi, are both the tenses correct? Which one would you prefer?

Comment: @user266865 'I had never had pizza before' is grammatical, but 'I have never had pizza before' is both grammatical and (as 'I've never had pizza before') what 99+% of native speakers would say in the actual example you give. The above answer and BillJ's comment are spot on;  'At the time of the utterance, your friend's eating/enjoyment of the pizza had current relevance' trumps 'by the time he spoke about not having pizza, he actually [had] had it' here. 'Rules' in English are often (perhaps usually) presented badly, inadequately, by instructors. And English often seems maddeningly illogical.

Answer (score 1):

your friend meant it like he never ever tasted pizza before and this is for the very first time he actually tasted a one and he likes it, so it should be "I've never eaten pizza before" or "this is (was) my very first pizza I've ever tasted"